# How to save Persian date time in SQL server?

Tags: .net, sql-server

In past projects, I tried to save my time format in Gregorian dates
and convert Gregorian dates to Persian in the logic layer of application, but I'm tired of doing it in that way.

I need save and restore date time with format of Persian in sql server without any conversion

Can type of datetime2 in sql server store Persian date time?

If not, what is the best way to store Persian date time?

Comment: Is this link of use : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28129/Creating-a-CLR-Persian-Date-Convertor-Function-for

Comment: What do you mean by "time format"? Dates have no format, they are binary values. You can create a DateTime object on the client side based on a Persian calendar, save it to the database and display it as persian when you retrieve it again. The *calendar* affects how dates are calculated, not how they are displayed.

Comment: For example, on my machine `DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fa-IR"))` returns `14/01/1396 03:17:13 ب.ظ` and I have no idea if that's correct or not. In all applications, for all cultures, if you want to display dates in a certain way, you set the application's CultureInfo or use a format string on the fields. The *default* culture comes from the user's locale. If the user uses `fa-IR`, `DateTime.Now.ToString()`  should also return `14/01/1396 03:17:13 ب.ظ`

Comment: I think that's the same.thanks

Comment: select format(getdate() , 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa-ir')

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql) in SQL Server uses the Gregorian calendar.

If you want to use dates based on the Persian calendar, then you either need to make and use some functions that you can call in your SQL code to do the conversion for you, or you need to make a [User Defined Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql) that can store the data.

Here's an [example](https://raresql.com/tag/iranian-calendar-to-georgian-calendar-in-sql-server/) of some functions that can convert between Persian and Gregorian. I haven't tried them out so I have no idea if they work, or to their quality.

I couldn't find an example of creating a UDT for Persian dates, but this is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-types/clr-user-defined-types) for UDTs in general.

Personally, I would store the dates in SQL Server as UTC Gregorian `datetime2`. And I'd either have conversion code in the application data layer that converts them when saving to, and loading from SQL Server, or I'd do the conversion when the `DateTime` is displayed to/retrieved from the user.

UTC is the date and time standard for the world, especially for science and engineering, and as such SQL Server and .Net have been built using it. It makes sense to also use UTC so that you can get the most benefit from the existing SQL Server and .Net code. Of course your users still want to be able to write and read a `DateTime` using the Persian calendar, so it makes sense to me that you'd perform that conversion just before one will be displayed to the user, or just after the user has provided one.

Comment: Does a computed column make any sense which can apply the conversion function to convert the Gregorian date into Persian date? I believe computed columns are computed on the fly rather than getting saved in the database. The computed column storing the converted data can be of varchar type.

Comment: @RBT why use a computed column at all? *Is* there a problem to begin with? Dates have no formats, they are binary values. If you want to display a date in a specific format, just use the appropriate culture on your application, or set the format string. You'd only need to change the storage type if the *date calculations* are different

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below functions to convert calendar to Persian and vice versa.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_Persian_To_Julian](@iYear int,@iMonth int,@iDay int)
RETURNS bigint
AS
Begin

Declare @PERSIAN_EPOCH  as int
Declare @epbase as bigint
Declare @epyear as bigint
Declare @mdays as bigint
Declare @Jofst  as Numeric(18,2)
Declare @jdn bigint

Set @PERSIAN_EPOCH=1948321
Set @Jofst=2415020.5

If @iYear>=0 
    Begin
        Set @epbase=@iyear-474 
    End
Else
    Begin
        Set @epbase = @iYear - 473 
    End
    set @epyear=474 + (@epbase%2820) 
If @iMonth<=7
    Begin
        Set @mdays=(Convert(bigint,(@iMonth) - 1) * 31)
    End
Else
    Begin
        Set @mdays=(Convert(bigint,(@iMonth) - 1) * 30+6)
    End
    Set @jdn =Convert(int,@iday) + @mdays+ Cast(((@epyear * 682) - 110) / 2816 as int)  + (@epyear - 1) * 365 + Cast(@epbase / 2820 as int) * 1029983 + (@PERSIAN_EPOCH - 1) 
   RETURN @jdn
End
```

and the second function is:

```
Create Function dbo.[UDF_Gregorian_To_Persian] (@date datetime)
Returns NvarChar(10) AS
begin

Declare @gd As int
Declare @gm As int
Declare @gm2 As int
Declare @gy As int
Declare @gy2 As int
Declare @jy as int
Declare @jd as int
Declare @jm as int
Declare @days as int
Declare @g_d_m as int

Declare @Result As NVarChar(10)

set @gy = YEAR(@date)
set @gm = MONTH(@date)
set @gd = DAY(@date)

if @gy <= 1600 
    set @jy = 0
else
    set @jy = 979

if @gy <= 1600 
    set @gy = @gy - 621
else
    set @gy = @gy - 1600

if @gm > 2 
    set @gy2 = @gy + 1
else
    set @gy2 = @gy

set @gm2 = @gm - 1

if @gm2 = 0
    set @g_d_m = 0
else if @gm2 = 1
    set @g_d_m = 31
else if @gm2 = 2
    set @g_d_m = 59
else if @gm2 = 3
    set @g_d_m = 90
else if @gm2 = 4
    set @g_d_m = 120
else if @gm2 = 5
    set @g_d_m = 151
else if @gm2 = 6
    set @g_d_m = 181
else if @gm2 = 7
    set @g_d_m = 212
else if @gm2 = 8
    set @g_d_m = 243
else if @gm2 = 9
    set @g_d_m = 273
else if @gm2 = 10
    set @g_d_m = 304
else if @gm2 = 11
    set @g_d_m = 334

set @days = (365 * @gy) + ((@gy2 + 3) / 4) - ((@gy2 + 99) / 100) + ((@gy2 + 399) / 400) - 80 + @gd + @g_d_m 
set @jy = @jy +  33 * (@days / 12053);
set @days = @days % 12053
set @jy = @jy + 4 * (@days / 1461)
set @days = @days % 1461
set @jy = @jy + ((@days - 1) / 365);

if @days > 365
    set @days = (@days - 1) % 365;

if @days < 186
    set @jm = 1 + (@days / 31) 
else
    set @jm = 7 + ((@days - 186) / 30);

if @days < 186
    set @jd = 1 + (@days % 31) 
else
    set @jd = 1 + ((@days - 186) % 30)

Return Convert(nvarchar(50),@jy) + '/' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@jm AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +'/' + RIGHT('0' + CAST(@jd AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
end
```

Example of using this function is:

```
SELECT [dbo].[UDF_Gregorian_To_Persian] ('2018-2-5') as PersianDate
```

Result is:

```
1396/11/16
```

Comment: i think user defined type is better idea , but anyway thank you for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, Please add a sample for "UDF_Persian_To_Julian"

Answer (score 3):

You can use in SQL SERVER 2016 above Persian format like this function :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [Fun].[PersianDateFormat]
(
    @Date   datetime ,      --تاریخ میلادی ورودی 
    @How    tinyint =1      --0.numberFull and time 1.numbers   2.Month latter  3.Day latter    4.Month and Day latter  5.just Month    6.Just Day
)
RETURNS Nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PersianDate Nvarchar(30)
    if @How = 0
        SELECT @PersianDate=FORMAT(@Date, 'yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss', 'fa')
    if @How = 1
        SELECT @PersianDate=FORMAT(@Date, 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'fa')
    if @How = 2
        SELECT @PersianDate=FORMAT(@Date, 'yyyy/MMM/dd', 'fa')
    if @how = 3
        SELECT @PersianDate=FORMAT(@Date, 'yyyy/MM/ddd', 'fa')      
    if @how = 4
        SELECT @PersianDate=FORMAT(@Date, 'yyyy/MMM/ddd', 'fa') 
    if @how = 5
        SELECT @PersianDate=FORMAT(@Date, 'MMM', 'fa')  
    if @how = 6
        SELECT @PersianDate=FORMAT(@Date, 'ddd', 'fa')  
    RETURN @PersianDate

END
```

You can use directly in query for change date to Persian like this :

```
Select FORMAT(Getdate(), 'yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss', 'fa')
```

I hope you wish the best