# How can I store Hijri date inside Sql Server DateTimeOffset column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetimeoffset

I am working on a legacy website and they are storing all Hijri dates inside **nvarchar(10)** column. Now they are rebuilding the system and they need to convert from **nvarchar(10)** into **DateTimeOffset** column.

When I try to use the following command to cast into **DateTimeOffset**:

> Select Cast('1444-02-30' as DateTimeOffset)

It shows me a conversion error as there are no 30 days in February.

So, does it mean that I cannot store Hijri dates inside **DateTimeOffset** column or is there a workaround I can apply to make it work?

Comment: SQL Server datetime types are based on the Gregorian calendar so you'll need to convert the Hijri dates to Gregorian for storage in datetimeoffset and other temporal types. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43180173/how-to-save-persian-date-time-in-sql-server) for possible solutions.